# What is this plant? Is this basil?

Tags: identification

I bought this at the grocery thinking it's basil, but I'm not really sure. Also, there was no label.

[image: is this basil]

Comment: Looks like basil. Crush a leaf and see if it smells appropriately

Comment: The smell is very typical. Use your nose!

Comment: I don't think this is Basil - the leaves are too elongated and pointed - Basil has somewhat rounder leaves, veined and without the long point on the end. But certainly pick and crush a leaf -  the smell of Basil is unmistakeable...

Comment: Looks a bit like a chili of some sort, but it's hard to say. Wait until it flowers & try again.

Comment: So apparently it's not basil (it doesn't smell like one) and I still don't know what it is.